# How to setup "drush @mysite.env ssh" command?

Tags: drush, ssh

I am trying to create a custom drush command in which I have to access another remote environment and run some drush commands there. The problem is I am unable to ssh to another environment e.g, "dev" etc.
I am able to run

```
drush @mysite.env status
```

but when I try

```
drush @mysite.env ssh
```

then I get this error

```
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Command not supported as typed.
An error 255 occurred while running the command `ssh -p 2222 -o AddressFamily inet"
```

"pantheon.aliases.drushrc.php" is placed in "~/.drush" folder.

Please let me know what's missing.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Pantheon does not support ssh access to your server. Write your own Drush command, place it in the `drush` folder at your repository root, and call it with `drush @mysite.env mycommand`.